# LinkedIn share links to PDF documents

Tags: file, pdf, plugins, share, linkedin-api

I am trying to create buttons on a web page that allow users to share links to PDF documents on LinkedIn. LinkedIn loads a window without any errors but offers no link or preview of the PDF or any indication of what is being shared.

Here are the two methods I have tried. First the plugin method.

```
<script type="in/share" data-url="http://example.net/DocumentDownload.aspx?Command=Core_Download&entryID=114"></script>
```

And, secondly with a custom url.

```
<a href="https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&http://example.net/DocumentDownload.aspx?Command=Core_Download&entryID=114">TEST</a>
```

Encoding the url makes no difference.

The above links are direct document links from a DNN web site using Document Exchange. If I change the urls to any html page it works fine and LinkedIn seems to be able to extract the useful information right from the page and use that for the share details.

Can LinkedIn handle this kind of thing? There is nothing to guide me on the type of links that can be shared. I can't find any information about it. There are no errors in the web console.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but you should try to provide LinkedIn with the link that has `.pdf` at the end, like `http://example.com/documents/file1.pdf`. I guess LinkedIn just checks the URL if it has `.pdf` file at the end to decide if it is a PDF document or not.

Comment: thanks for the comment but I already tried that and get the same result. Direct link to .pdf does not work either.  However, I tried a share today and although there appeared to be nothing getting shared the person I shared it with did receive a link. But it was an empty text box that was a hyperlink when hovered over.  Bit of a mess really.

Comment: I don't think LinkedIn is really downloading the PDF and making a preview. Maybe it requests some predefined preview link, like http://example.com/documents/file1.pdf_preview.jpg. The only way to find this is to check logs during the share of your link to find if LinkedIn is trying to request some additional images from your server?

Comment: @NorbertNorbertson server side logs, to check if LinkedIn was trying to request the preview image

Comment: Ok, before I spend loads of time investigating that let's assume that LinkedIn IS trying to request a preview image and failing. That would mean having to create and store a preview image for every document in the library which is not practical right now.  It would be so much more helpful if LinkedIn had some documentation on this.

Comment: I think I'll just have to drop the idea of LinkedIn sharing for documents. It just doesn't work and that's their fault.

Comment: Have you checked AddThis and SumoMe? They provide fast way to add sharing via their widgets but be careful of their privacy policy too.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem sharing pdf's on LinkedIn.  Check it out...

> https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https://www.revoltlib.com/anarchism/the-conquest-of-bread/view.pdf

[image: linkedin-pdf-working]

Works perfectly fine.  And `view.pdf` is a script, not a file, either, so, it's not looking for a PDF file to analyze, so much as headers that indicate you have a PDF file available to analyze, so, in PHP, at DocumentDownload.aspx, we would do...

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf; charset=utf-8');
```

This header let's the sharing app know that it can analyze the document as a PDF file and extract useful information from it, as you can see from the screen shot.